# Поместить плавающий блок в ряд с предыдущим

Tags: html, css

Написал такой код. Планируется что слева в каждом блоке будет картинка, а справа будет сверху название, снизу описание. Но проблема в том что блок с текстом из-за длины занимает все 100% блока и переносится на следующую строку.

Как сделать что бы текст не переносило на следующую строку, при этом сохранив гибкость, то есть не задавая ширину блоков, она может постоянно меняться позже?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6arnozcs/

```css
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.shop_block {
 max-height: 300px;
 overflow: auto;
    width: 400px;
}
.shop_item {
    background: #ccc;
}
.shop_item:hover {
 background: #999;
}
.shop_item>div {
 float: left;
}
.shopitem_cont {
 height: 64px;
    overflow: hidden;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 5px 10px 3px 8px;
}
.shopitem_head {
 font-size: 18px;
 padding: 0 0 3px 0;
 margin: 0 0 3px 0;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="shop_block">
  <div class="shop_item clearfix">
   <div class="shopitem_image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/64x64">
   </div>
   <div class="shopitem_cont">
    <div class="shopitem_head">Item 0</div>
    Description is here. На самом деле описание настоооолько большое что просто  не влазит в этот блок. 
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="shop_item clearfix">
   <div class="shopitem_image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/64x64">
   </div>
   <div class="shopitem_cont">
    <div class="shopitem_head">Item 0</div>
    Description is here. На самом деле описание настоооолько большое что просто не влазит в этот блок. 
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть прекрасная связка `float: left / right;` + `overflow: hidden`. Выглядит эта техника вот так:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}
.container:after {
  display: table;
  content: '';
  clear: both;
}
.container__left {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
.container__right {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.container__right p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__left">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/64x64" />
  </div>
  <div class="container__right">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At harum eaque sint.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="container__left">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/128x64" />
  </div>
  <div class="container__right">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At harum eaque sint. Quas sint quia repellat, qui blanditiis odit harum delectus cum illum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ну а вообще — пользуйтесь флексбоксом, если позволяет стек браузеров : )

Comment: Я пока не имел дела с flexbox, но все факты говорят что пора бы. Большущее спасибо!